# iOS Push Notification service batch size

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

We are trying to send a notification to ~500,000 iOS devices. We have currently set the batch size to 200 and are noticing that Apple refuses our connection after 300k messages or so. We suspect that Apple interprets our connection/tear-downs to be a DOS attack. What is a good batch size for us to use? Also, any tips on sending notifications for such a large number of devices?

Answer (score 2):

Your push notification server must maintain a persistent connection to Apple's socket stream push server without disconnecting too often.

I recommend writing your push server using Node.js, it was designed for this stuff.

However there are a few things that can also cause Apple to disconnect your push server.

With Push Notification, there are two types of certificates - development and production.

An app signed with a development certificate will generate a development push token whereas a an app signed with a production certificate will generate a different production push token even on the same device.

Your server must make sure it does not send a development token to a production socket stream connection to Apple's push server.

Mixing the token and environment will cause Apple's push server to disconnect your push server.

How you separate your push token is something that you need to build into your server.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your response! We have all of the covered. We have modified [Apns-php](http://code.google.com/p/apns-php/) to suit our needs and have successfully sent ~300k notifications using the production certificate. Apple still abruptly disconnects our connections. We can't seem to figure out why!